# Mount in linux a shared folder from windows

Tags: mount, nfs

I created a shared folder on winwdows (on `C:\sharedfolder`) and i need to mount (in linux) the shared folder on the `/mnt/folder`.

The windows folder has enabled unmapped user access and read only option.

Here are the steps i made:

- create `/mnt/sharedfolder`
- install `cifs`
- command: `sudo mount.cifs C:/sharedfolder /mnt/folder`, but i receive the error: `bad UNC (C:/sharedfolder)`

ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From `man mount.cifs`:

```
mount.cifs //server/share /mnt -o user=username
```

There are many more `-o` options too.

Basically, the `C:/` in your command does not mean anything to the Linux machine. You need to change `server` to the network name of the server which has the share on it. You can also use the IP of the Windows PC instead of `server`.

You could also install and use [Samba](https://www.samba.org/) which is designed for accessing Windows Shares from many different operating systems.